# ¿Qué quiere decir "espinazo partido"?

Tags: expresiones, significado, cuerpo-humano

Leí el texto siguiente:

> Estaban dos aldeanos, padre e hijo, con el **espinazo partido** labrando en un campo de Castilla al borde de una carretera, cuando llega un conductor en un lujoso coche.

¿Qué  quiere decir "espinazo partido" en ese contexto? Seguramente no es su sentido literal.

Comment: currando intensamente y fisicamente

Answer (score 4, accepted):

De acuerdo con el DLE

> espinazo De espina.
>
> 1. m. **columna vertebral** (‖ eje del neuroesqueleto de los vertebrados).
> 2. m. Clave de una bóveda o de un arco.
>
> **doblar el espinazo**
>
> 1. loc. verb. coloq. Humillarse para acatar servilmente.

Nótese que he remarcado la expresión "doblar el espinazo" que guarda cierta relación. En el texto referenciado nos encontramos con una **hipérbole**, tienen el espinazo / columna vertebral / espalda tan doblado que podríamos decir que se lo han partido. Yo entiendo que el texto refleja que llevan mucho tiempo trabajando y con la espalda doblada.

Encontramos una construcción similar en la [expresión](https://www.lexico.com/es/definicion/a_brazo_partido)

> **a brazo partido** 
> LOCUCIÓN
>  1 Con gran esfuerzo y energía.

que indica, hiperbólicamente también, trabajar o esforzarse hasta que el brazo se haya partido.

Comment: Correcto. Normalmente diríamos "con la espalda rota".

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, de acuerdo que es una hipérbole. Cuando yo dije que la expresión "espinazo partido" no tenía su sentido literal, me referí a la expresión entera, no sólo la palabra "espinazo". Por lo que sé, si alguién parte el espinazo, lo rompe y possiblemente nunca más podrá caminar. No entendí tu uso de la palabra "literalmente" en la explicación de "brazo partido". No creo que el significado sea literal, sino otra hipérbole. Si partes el brazo de tanto esforzarse, vas a necesitar de ponerlo en un yeso o hacer una cirugía.

Comment: @AlanEvangelista De nada. Quizás ambos "literal" que aparecen en mi respuesta induzcan a confusión. Los elimino. De acuerdo contigo en que "a brazo partido" también es una hipérbole.

Answer (score 1):

Era muy común en Castilla usar esa expresión, ya que trabajaban en el campo largas jornadas para recoger la cosecha o plantar las semillas. No había maquinaría, tenían que doblarse y terminaban con la columna vertebral, dañada y la espalda dolorida de tanto esfuerzo. Coloquialmente, la llamaban el espinazo y de ahí la expresión hiperbólica. También se usaba "lomo". En lenguaje coloquial significa trabajar hasta extenuarte.